# What is the most efficient way to delete all selected items in a ListViewItem collection?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My user is able to select multiple items in a `ListView` collection that is configured to show details (that is, a list of rows).

What I want to do is add a `Delete` button that will delete all of the selected items from the `ListViewItem` collection associated with the `ListView`.

The collection of selected items is available in `ListView.SelectedItems`, but `ListView.Items` doesn't appear to have a single method that lets me delete the entire range. I have to iterate through the range and delete them one by one, which will potentially modify a collection I'm iterating over.

So, what I'm basically after is the opposite of `AddRange()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a collecion of your selectedItems, you can simply call remove on each of them instead of iterating over the ListView.

There is a method on ListViewItem called [Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.remove.aspx).

```
ListView listview = <reference to ListView>;
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedItems)
{
  item.Remove();
}
```

This removes the iteration through all the items and only removes your selected items.

Comment: This worked perfectly. It's the most succinct way I've seen so far; thanks Ray.

Comment: Sure thing.  The cool thing about ListViewItems is that they keep a reference to their ListView, which makes this probably the fastest way to do it and only has one iteration

Comment: I've wrapped your little snippet into an extension method for `ListView` objects, so I've now got a simple call to `RemoveAllSelectedItems()`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way other than to delete them individually.

Wrap your deletion algorithm in `ListView.BeginUpdate()` and `ListView.EndUpdate()` calls. This way you won't get the slowdown of repainting on each delete.

Additionally, if you delete them in reverse order, I believe the underlying structure will have less to do.

Also, if the number of items you are deleting is a significant percentage of the total number of items, you might get more performance by clearing the list and `AddRange()`ing them back again.

Comment: Deleting in reverse order doesn't seem to be faster. ListViewNativeItemCollection.IndexOf is called for every removal and it iterates starting at 1st item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in linq 2 sql I use:

```
mylist.Clear();
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could try something along the lines of the following:

```
var ItemsToDelete = ... // wherever you get the collection of items to delete from
var RemainingItems = yourList.FindAll(delegate(ListItem x) {
  return !ItemsToDelete.Contains(x)
});
yourListView.DataSource = RemainingItems;
yourListView.DataBind();
```

or just assign the remaining items to the existing control, or whatever you prefer.

*(edited formatting slightly)*

Comment: Thats pretty inefficient.  For each item in the listview, you're iterating over the ItemsToDelete collection.